# why parseInt() in javascript converting "1abc" to 1?

Tags: javascript, parseint

I am trying to understand how parseInt() will work in javascript, my scenarios are

`var x = parseInt("123");
console.log(x); // outputs 123`

`var x = parseInt("1abc");
console.log(x); // outputs 1`

`var x = parseInt("abc");
console.log(x); // outputs NaN`

as of my observation parseInt() converts a string to integer(not really an integer of string like "12sv") when the string begins with number.

but in reality it should return NaN.

Comment: It's just code trying to do its best with what it's got :) if you try `parseInt( 'abc123efg' )` you'll get NaN -- it looks at the string and tries its best to convert, if it can.

Comment: If you want NaN use the Number constructor ->  `Number("abc")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

"If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN."

Answer (score 1):

From [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt): "If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point."

So it will parse up to the first invalid character, drop the rest of the string, and return the int it managed to parse until then. If there's no valid characters it will return NaN.

Comment: so that means, parseInt() will look character by character while converting?

Comment: These docs don't explicitly state so, but it seems like it rom the behaviour described... Read the link for further info on special characters like "x" and "e", they even recommend writing a stricter parser yourself and give an example at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt()`->it simply parse the provided value to its equivalent radix conversion,if specified without radix it converts to decimal equivalent.

for coercion purpose, we should avoid using parseInt,we can use `Number()` function instead.